# When is information about marks in Vim loaded?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to learn vimscript by writing a small plugin to display marks using the signs feature. When I call a function in the plugin (from the plugin itself) it doesn't return anything. However, if I call it manually after Vim opens up, it returns the list of marks set correctly.

My question is when is the information about marks available in Vim? Is it before or after the plugins are loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should type `:help startup` to get some help.

vim loads `viminfo` after `plugin`.

Try `autocmd`.